# How can I accomplish multiprocessing as a Windows service created with py2exe?

Tags: python-2.7, windows-services, py2exe, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess a python application using the multiprocessing library. I got it working running from the command line and also running as an executable created by py2exe.

I also got it working running the service created by py2exe by modifying forking.py as in this [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue6461). Then get_command_line in forking.py returns the command:

```
"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "-c" "from multiprocessing.forking import main; main()" "--multiprocessing-fork" "56208"
```

This then requires you to have python installed to run the application, which is not feasible for us.

Without modifying forking.py, the command that get_command_line returns is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyService.exe" "--multiprocessing-fork" "56228"
```

Putting log statements in forking.py in Popen.__init__, which is called from Process.start in process.py, I see the pid of the child process that is supposed to be created. Looking at the running processes on my computer, no process with that pid exists.

How can I get this working?